# how to upgrade to latest version of ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed in my laptop. How can I upgrade it to the latest version without upgrading to 11.04? Also how much time will this take? I do not want to lose any data. I also have Windows 7 in my machine.